# Fiware - run Cosmos CLI error

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Im trying to run code from 
http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/BigData_Analysis_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide

And Im stuck at line

> "easy_install
>   https://forge.fi-ware.org/frs/download.php/1309/cosmos-0.16.0-py2.7.egg"

System print out:

```
Downloading https://forge.fi-ware.org/frs/download.php/1309/cosmos-0.16.0-py2.7.egg
Processing cosmos-0.16.0-py2.7.egg
removing '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cosmos-0.16.0-py2.7.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cosmos-0.16.0-py2.7.egg
Extracting cosmos-0.16.0-py2.7.egg to /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cosmos-0.16.0-py2.7.egg/cosmos/cli/command_util.py', 145, 20, '    return {k: v for k, v in json.iteritems() if k not in filter_keys}\n'))

cosmos 0.16.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing cosmos script to /usr/bin

Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cosmos-0.16.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for cosmos==0.16.0
Searching for cosmos==0.16.0
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cosmos/
No local packages or download links found for cosmos==0.16.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cosmos==0.16.0')
```

But after that I realized that Im using image from conference and cosmos should be installed, so I run

```
# cosmos
```

And this is my system print out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cosmos", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: requests
```

How to run cosmos properly ??

Comment: it looks like you are missing python packages (requests): `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: requests`

Comment: Ok, thank You LeandroGuillen for quick answer :) this error is from fiware labs instance with proper credentials, and problem is that I dont have root access there ? what do you sugest to do in this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the already deployed Hadoop-like Cosmos instance in FIWARE LAB you don't need the Cosmos CLI; that's intended to create new clusters on demand on a Hadoop-as-a-service-like Cosmos deployment, which is not the case of FIWARE LAB one.

Simply go [here](http://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org/cosmos-gui/) and create a Cosmos account by using your FIWARE LAB credentials. Then, follow the steps pointed in that web.

Regarding the [Cosmos documentation](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/BigData_Analysis_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide), please ignore the first sections until section 2.3.

Comment: Thank You :), so you are telling me that command "cosmos" will not work on FIWARE LAB ?? becacuse as i wrote I have credentials and Im  logged to fiware account and command "cosmos" is not found :)
Is it proper to say that Cosmos is Hadoop ??

Comment: In the case of FIWARE LAB, due to limitation of resoureces, yes, it is a Hadoop shared cluster.